# how to make an action on drop down menu click?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i have a simple dropdown menu like this below:

```
<select name="category[]" id="category" class="icon-menu">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="misc">misc</option>
  <option value="travel">travel</option>
  <option value="weather">weather</option>
  <option value="shopping">shopping</option>
  <option value="restaurant">restaurant</option>
  <option value="food">food</option>
  <option value="kitchen">kitchen</option>
  ...
```

and also some css making a picture in the background of each option.  But i see  on other sites often, that an action is done when you click on one of the options in the drop down menu. like the form being submitted on the click of the option. but mine you have to click on the option then click submit.

i imagined it would be a simple change, but i cant find the answer...

Comment: What do you want to do when an option is selected?

Comment: the form to be submitted with the selected value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to bind the onchange event to a javascript function i.e

```
<select id="category" class="icon-menu" onchange="myFunction()"></select>
```

... and in your javascript file

```
function myFunction()
{
   document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: this does make it submit, but it does not submit a value... And the form does work when i chose and then click submit

Comment: what server technology do you use? mainly you have two choices.  Either make the dropdown a server control or save the selected value in a hidden input and then read that value from the backend.

Comment: bluehost, apache, i dont really understand the options you describe so show me either and i'll be happy...

Comment: i changed it to onchange="this.form.submit()" and it works just fine now. thanks for your help

Comment: Cool. I would advise you to test that in different browsers because the standard way of referencing a form in JS is to use document.forms[formName] or document.forms[formIndex]